# Pygame OGG and audio issues

Tags: python, audio, pygame, pygame-mixer

I have been recently working on a new game and I am finally finished with it and I was adding some music as some last touches but then I realized that the sounds were very poor quality and so I tried to make it into different extensions and wav, mp3 don't work and I was trying OGG and it says it 'failed to load'. I need help either fixing the OGG loading or fixing the poor quality given with wav and mp3.
I am on windows 10
Here I load the audio files:

```
intro_mp3 = mixer.Sound("audio/intro.ogg")
choosing_mp3 = mixer.Sound('audio/choosing.ogg')
battle_mp3 = mixer.Sound('audio/battle.ogg')
win_mp3 = mixer.Sound('audio/win.ogg')
lose_mp3 = mixer.Sound('audio/lose.ogg')
```

and here I play it outside of this if statement:

```
if start_button.draw(screen):
        sleep(0.2)
        game_screen()
        start_button.remove()
        start.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
        intro = True
        chosen_fighter = True
        bool_appearer = True
        print("START")
        screen.blit(tutorial, (50, 0))
    intro_mp3.play()
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "poor quality"? How do they sound different to playing them in a stand-alone player. Also, you're using `time.sleep()` which might be causing problems, you should use a state machine / counter or a timer event. A [mcve] would make it possible to help you.

Comment: Are you able to play the OGG file in a stand-alone player?

Comment: "and here I play it outside of this if statement" - The `intro_mp3.play()` line is clearly located inside the if statement. Has there gone anything wrong with the indentation?

Comment: The poor quality is describable as it echoing over and over, I am able to play it in a stand_alone player, plays fine. The spacing went wrong and in the source code everything is 1 tab behind except for the if statement

Answer (score 0):

There is very little code provided in the question for analysis.

You describe the sound as "echoing over and over", this makes me believe your code is repeatedly asking the `pygame.mixer.Sound` object to [play()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.play) the sound, *without* waiting for the sound to complete.  Maybe it's starting a new playback every time some loop executes.  Probably the design did not intend for this to happen.

Calling `.Sound.play()` only *starts* the playback, the function does not block, it returns almost immediately.

The `.Sound.play()` call returns the [pygame.mixer.Channel](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel) object on which the sound is playing.  Your code could call the `.get_busy()` member function on the Channel to see if the sound was still playing, and *not* play it a second time.  (Although `get_busy()` returns true if *any* sound is playing, not just a particular one).

Obviously the best fix is re-structure the code so the sound playback is only triggered a single time.